# Html and CSS rules

Tags: html, css

I follow this steps and still error in the Html anyone can fix the Html code (The CSS code is right)

1- The stylesheet is correctly referenced in the index.html page.
2- There is a menu header that prefaces the menu items and their prices.
3- There is a food menu that contains a sub-header and three menu items with their respective prices.
4- There is a drink menu that contains a sub-header and three menu items with their respective prices.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <header class="container">
    <h1 id="main-header">Codey's Cafe</h1>
  </header>
  <body>
    <header></header>

    <div class="container">
      <img
        src=" https://cutt.ly/qwuJkUFO"
        id="main-img"
      />
    </div>

    <main>
      <article>
        <header class="menu-container">
          <h2 id="menu-header">Menu</h2>
        </header>

        <section class="menu-container">
          <header class="menu-subheaders">
            <h3>Food</h3>
          </header>
          <h4 class="menu-item">Chili Cheese Dog</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$4.50</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Basket of Fries</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$4.00</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Hamburger</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$6.00</h5>

          <h5 class="item-price">Add cheese for $1</h5>
        </section>

        <section class="menu-container">
          <header class="menu-subheaders">
            <h3>Drinks</h3>
          </header>
          <h4 class="menu-item">Vanilla Milkshake</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$6.00</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Fresh Squeezed Lemonade</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$4.00</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Fountain Drink</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$3.00</h5>
        </section>
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
 .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;   
}

#main-header {
    font-size: 8vw;
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    color: Crimson;
}

#main-img {
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
}

.menu-container {
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-header {
    font-size: 7.5vw;
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    color: Blue;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.menu-subheaders {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: Sienna;
}

.menu-item {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: Darkslategrey
}

.item-price {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: Slategrey;
}
```

Fix the rulset in html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn the difference between [`<head>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp) and [`<header>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp). The former refers to your HTML as a document; it contains metadata describing the document and how it links to other documents. The latter refers to the visible webpage which is seen by the user; it’s like a `<div>`, it’s a container element into which you place the elements which comprise the top part of your page design, typically the part which would be repeated on every page of a site.

You need to add a `<head>` tag before the `<body>` tag, and place your stylesheet `<link>` into it. Then move your `<header>` tag inside the `<body>` tag. The first part of your HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="container">
      <h1 id="main-header">Codey's Cafe</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <img
        src=" https://cutt.ly/qwuJkUFO"
        id="main-img"
      />
    </div>

    ...
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate the working webpage

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;   
}

#main-header {
    font-size: 8vw;
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    color: Crimson;
}

#main-img {
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
}

.menu-container {
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-header {
    font-size: 7.5vw;
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    color: Blue;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.menu-subheaders {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: Sienna;
}

.menu-item {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: Darkslategrey
}

.item-price {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: Slategrey;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="main-header">Codey's Cafe</h1>

    <div class="container">
      <img
        src=" https://cutt.ly/qwuJkUFO"
        id="main-img"
      />
    </div>

    <main>
      <article>
        <header class="menu-container">
          <h2 id="menu-header">Menu</h2>
        </header>

        <section class="menu-container">
          <header class="menu-subheaders">
            <h3>Food</h3>
          </header>
          <h4 class="menu-item">Chili Cheese Dog</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$4.50</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Basket of Fries</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$4.00</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Hamburger</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$6.00</h5>

          <h5 class="item-price">Add cheese for $1</h5>
        </section>

        <section class="menu-container">
          <header class="menu-subheaders">
            <h3>Drinks</h3>
          </header>
          <h4 class="menu-item">Vanilla Milkshake</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$6.00</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Fresh Squeezed Lemonade</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$4.00</h5>

          <h4 class="menu-item">Fountain Drink</h4>
          <h5 class="item-price">$3.00</h5>
        </section>
      </article>
    </main>
```